# getSupportFragmentManager() "cannot resolve method" in class that supports my fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently the class that I'm trying to use getSupportFragmentManager() in is passed an Activity object from another activity that extends Fragment.

No matter what I try with my passed activity (mActivity);
`mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` or
`mActivity.getApplicationContext.getSupportFragmentManager()`

getSupportFragmentManager() is always an un-resolvable method, does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you have an actual code snippet of where the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Activity` doesn't offer a `FragmentManager`, you'll need to extend/cast to `FragmentActivity`, which extends the `Activity` class.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
GetActivity.GetSupportFragementManager();
```